# Show not the first page on start

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I want to show a table from the second page on start. I've used the following to set the second page.

```
pagination.start = pagination.start || 10;
```

After this I see the second page and may navigate to other pages, but can't go to the first.

I have created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mATAk76pEWmSRBiX9EC5) about the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When You try to load page 1, `pagination.start == 0`, and `0 || 10` returns 10. If You want to load second page only at start, You can use a flag to indicate, is it first load or not, like this:

```
var first = true;

this.callServer = function callServer(tableState) {

    ...

    pagination.start = first ? 10 : pagination.start;
    first = false;
```

Forked Your plunkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/sdMT9IXfRD739OVpdW8s)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Looks like JS knowledge issue =)